# C# program displays System.String[] instead of displaying a string

Tags: c#, string, system

I am trying to make a program that takes a character list and a list of selection moves and after making all the moves to display the resulted character selected.

The problem is that I am a beginner and my program displays System.String[] instead of the string representing the character. I tried to search in the Microsoft documentation but I haven't found anything related to my problem so I can understand why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you very much!

---

Below is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[][] fighters = new string[][]
        {
          new string[] { "Ryu", "E.Honda", "Blanka", "Guile", "Balrog", "Vega" },
          new string[] { "Ken", "Chun Li", "Zangief", "Dhalsim", "Sagat", "M.Bison" }
        };

        string[] moves = new string[] {"up", "left", "right", "left", "left"};

        int[] position = new int[] {0, 0};

        Console.WriteLine(StreetFighterSelection(fighters, position, moves));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string[] StreetFighterSelection(string[][] fighters, int[] position, string[] moves)
    {
        string[] fighter = new string[] { fighters[position[0]][position[1]] };

        for (int i = 0; i < moves.Length; i++)
        {
            if (moves[i] == "up" && position[0] == 1)
                position[0] -= 1;
            if (moves[i] == "down" && position[0] == 0)
                position[0] += 1;
            if (moves[i] == "right")
            {
                if (position[1] == fighters.GetLength(position[0]))
                {
                    position[1] = 0;
                }   
                else
                {
                    position[1] += 1;
                }
            }
            if (moves[i] == "left")
            {
                if (position[1] == 0)
                {
                    position[1] = fighters.GetLength(position[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    position[1] -= 1;
                }
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        return fighter;
    }
```

Comment: string[] is an array of strings.

You could iterate through the array, or only write one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an object to Console.WriteLine the ToString method of the object is executed. In this case, it shows it's a string[]. You should iterate over the string objects of the string array and display them.

```
foreach(var fighter in StreetFighterSelection(fighters, position, moves))
{
    Console.WriteLine(fighter);
}
```

Or you could join the strings into a new string separated by comma:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", StreetFighterSelection(fighters, position, moves)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ideed using the foreach solved the problem